# How to filter subcategory data from parent category in Laravel8

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to filter subcategory data according to parent category.
I am getting all my subcategory inside all the categories. I tried many old answers from stackoverflow and youtube but not worked.

I want this filter inside my article post form.

create.article.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ URL::to('post-article-form') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Article Name <b style="color: red">*</b></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter article title" name="articleTitle" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> Select Article category </label>
            <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category" required>
                <option value=""> Select </option>
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <option value="{{ $category->id }}"> {{ $category->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> Select Sub category </label>
            <select class="form-control" name="subCategory" id="subCategory" required>
                <option value=""> Select </option>
                @foreach($subCategories as $subCategory)
                    <option value="{{ $subCategory->id }}"> {{ $subCategory->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
```

I used this below script for filter but not worked.

```
   <script>
     $('#category').on('change',function(e){
      console.log(e);
      var cat_id = e.target.value;
       //ajax

      $.get('/ajax-subcat?cat_id='+cat_id, function(data){
         //subcategory
        $('#subCategory').empty();
        $('#subCategory').append($("<option></option>").val("").html("--Select Sub Category--"));
        $.each(data,function(index, subcatObj){
       $('#subCategory').append('<option value="'+subcatObj.id+'">'+subcatObj.name+'</option>');
        })
    })
});
        </script>
```

My web.php route

```
//sub category
Route::get('add-sub-category', [SubCategoryController::class, 'create']);
Route::post('post-sub-category-form', [SubCategoryController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('subcategories', [SubCategoryController::class, 'index']);

Route::get("/ajax-subcat", function (Request $request){
    $cat_id = $request-> Input::get('cat_id');
    $subCategories = SubCategory::where('category_id',$cat_id)->get();

    return response()->json($subCategories);

    });
```

Comment: You say it does not work as you built it now. Can you specify what result you are getting now?

Comment: I am getting all sub categories after selecting any category.